# Regular expression depending on length

Tags: regular-expression

A regular expression that accepts only lines of length multiple of 5 plus 2. For example: 7, 12, 32 etc. Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) tell us what regular expression language you are using, what tool will this be for? ii) give us some example input and your desired output. If you just want to measure the length, why would you use a regex?

Comment: Do you consider that `2` is a `multiple of 5 plus 2`?  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_(mathematics)#Properties) says it is, but some people aren't sure it's what you mean, because you are starting with `7` in your example.

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to use a regular expression, “^..(.{5})+$” interpreted as an extended regex does the trick; you can use it for example with `grep -E`:

```
for i in {1..20}; do printf "%.${i}s\n" --------------------; done | grep -E '^..(.{5})+$'
```

This can be rewritten as a basic regex, “^..(.{5})+$”.

Both these expressions are anchored to the start and end of the matched text, so they match full lines. “..” matches any two characters, “(.{5})” matches any five characters, and “+” repeats this last match at least once. This thus checks that each line contains a number of characters which is equal to 5×*n*+2 for *n* > 0.

Alternatively, other tools can check line lengths very quickly:

```
... | awk 'length > 5 && length % 5 == 2'
```

Comment: Stephen : I think you should use `+` instead of `*` before `$`

Comment: @StalinVigneshKumar 2 is 0*5+2, so it seems correct to use `*`.

Comment: @Kusalananda : okay, But seems OP only wants from multiples of 5 + 2 , which starts from 7.

Comment: `^..\(.\{5\}\)*$` would be the equivalent basic regular expression for use with standard `grep`, `sed` etc.

Comment: This will print lines with length 2 also .